# Unable to open attachment in Windows Live Mail 2011 (Build 15.4.3502.0922)

Tags: windows-7, email, attachments, windows-live-mail

I use Windows Live Mail 2011 (Build 15.4.3502.0922), in Windows 7 Pro 64. When I receive an email message that has an attachment, when I double click to open this attachment, nothing happens. Any kind of attachment, nothing happens. If I right click and choose "Open", nothing happens either. If I right click and choose Save As, I can save the file to disk and open it via Windows Explorer.

I would like to be able to double click to open the attachment. I tried to repair WLM but that didn't make any difference.

My antivirus is Microsoft Security Essentials.

Does anyone know anything about this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In WLM, go to Tools>Safety Options>Security Tab.

If you don't see the tools menu see this article
http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/windows_live_mail/windows-live-mail-toolbar.php

In there there will be a tick box about not allowing to save or open attacments that could be viruses, untick it, hit OK, see if you can open them.

Just so you know, you are know able to open potentially harmful attachments that could introduce a virus into your system, be careful what you open.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Moab. In my case I unchecked the "Dot not allow attachments..." option, clicked Ok, but the issue persists. I think this is a different issue, because even a .TXT file doesn't open. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you have a 3rd party security software blocking all email attachments?

Comment: The only thing is Microsoft Security Essentials. Strange. I also run CCleaner from time to time.

Comment: It may be a bug in WLM, I would backup your email, accounts and contacts, uninstall WLM and install the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run Windows Live Mail as administrator.

To do it once, right-click its shortcut or the start menu entry and select *Run as administrator*.

For a permanent solution, check *Run as administrator* in the *Advanced* tab of Windows Live Mail's *Properties* window.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved after I cleaned up all temporary internet explorer files. Tools, Internet Options, Delete button.
Thanks

Comment: solves his own problem, nice!